# TensorFlow Addition Error when adding results from binary_crossentropy() together

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I was in the middle of training my gan when a very unexpected error came up. I have no idea how to fix it. The error doesn't come right away it happens about 2-3 minutes into my training. Here is the Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "gan.py", line 103, in <module>
    train(X_train_dataset,200)
  File "gan.py", line 80, in train
    train_step(images) # takes images and improves both the generator and the discriminator
  File "gan.py", line 91, in train_step
    discriminator_loss = get_discriminator_loss(real_output,fake_output)
  File "gan.py", line 48, in get_discriminator_loss
    return fake_loss+real_loss
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1125, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1447, in _add_dispatch
    return gen_math_ops.add_v2(x, y, name=name)
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 486, in add_v2
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6843, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [100] vs. [13] [Op:AddV2]
```

So from I can tell from this call back my error occures during my get_discriminator_loss() so here is that code.

```
def get_discriminator_loss(real_predictions,fake_predictions):
    real_predictions = tf.sigmoid(real_predictions)
    fake_predictions = tf.sigmoid(fake_predictions)
    real_loss=tf.losses.binary_crossentropy(tf.ones_like(real_predictions),real_predictions)
    fake_loss=tf.losses.binary_crossentropy(tf.zeros_like(fake_predictions),fake_predictions)
    return fake_loss+real_loss
```

Does anyone have any ideas? And remember this is after running successfully for about 2-3 minutes. The error doesn't occur in the first many passes.

I've found the source of my error but I don't know why it's occuring.

My real loss at one of the passes has only 13 values instead of the normal 100

How can this be?

Here is my full code.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
import pickle

pickle_in_X = open("X.pickle","rb")
pickle_in_y = open("y.pickle","rb")

X=pickle.load(pickle_in_X)
y = pickle.load(pickle_in_y)
y = np.array(y)


X_train = X[  int(len(X)*.3):  ]
y_train = y[  int(len(y)*.3 ):  ]

X_test = X[  :int(len(X)*.3)  ]
y_test = X[  :int(len(y)*.3)    ]

X_train = (X_train-127.5)/127.5

BATCH_SIZE = 100
X_train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_train).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

#creates a discriminator model.
#discriminator will ouput 0-1 which represents the probability that the image is real
def make_discriminator():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(7,(3,3),padding="same",input_shape=(40,40,1)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50,activation="relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
    return model

model_discriminator = make_discriminator()
discriminator_optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(1e-3)

#real_loss is the amount of error when trying to guess that the real images are in fact real. i.e loss will be if our discriminator guesses that there is a 100% chance that this real image is real
#fake_loss is the amount of error when trying to guess that the fake images are in fact fake. i.e loss will be zero if our discriminator guesses there is a 0% chance that this fake image is fake
#returns the total of our loss
def get_discriminator_loss(real_predictions,fake_predictions):
    real_predictions = tf.sigmoid(real_predictions)
    fake_predictions = tf.sigmoid(fake_predictions)
    real_loss=tf.losses.binary_crossentropy(tf.ones_like(real_predictions),real_predictions)
    fake_loss=tf.losses.binary_crossentropy(tf.zeros_like(fake_predictions),fake_predictions)
    return fake_loss+real_loss

#take an input of a random string of numbers. and output either a dog or a cat
def make_generator():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10*10*256,input_shape = (100,)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((10,10,256)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128,(3,3),padding="same"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64,(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding="same"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1,(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding="same"))
    return model

model_generator = make_generator()

#generator gets rewarded when it fools the discriminator
def get_generator_loss(fake_predictions):
    fake_predictions = tf.sigmoid(fake_predictions)
    fake_loss=tf.losses.binary_crossentropy(tf.ones_like(fake_predictions),fake_predictions)
    return fake_loss

generator_optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(1e-3)


#training

def train(X_train_dataset,epochs):
    for _ in range(epochs):
        for images in X_train_dataset:
            images = tf.cast(images,tf.dtypes.float32)
            train_step(images) # takes images and improves both the generator and the discriminator


def train_step(images):
    fake_image_noise = np.random.randn(BATCH_SIZE,100)#produces 100 random numbers that wll be converted to images
    with tf.GradientTape() as generator_gradient, tf.GradientTape() as discriminator_gradient:
        generated_images = model_generator(fake_image_noise)
        real_output = model_discriminator(images)
        fake_output = model_discriminator(generated_images)

        generator_loss = get_generator_loss(fake_output)
        discriminator_loss = get_discriminator_loss(real_output,fake_output)

        gradients_of_generator = generator_gradient.gradient(generator_loss,model_generator.trainable_variables)#gradient of gen loss with respect to trainable variables
        gradients_of_discriminator = discriminator_gradient.gradient(discriminator_loss,model_discriminator.trainable_variables)
        
        discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator,model_discriminator.trainable_variables))
        generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator,model_generator.trainable_variables))

        print("generator loss: ", np.mean(generator_loss))
        print("discriminator loss: ",np.mean(discriminator_loss))


train(X_train_dataset,200)

model_generator.save('genModel')

model_discriminator.save('discModel')
```

Comment: Can you try using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_train).batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)` ? This could be that the batch at the end of the epoch is smaller than the other batches.

Comment: @jakub thank you so much. I never would have figured this out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

If the size of your dataset is not a multiple of your batch size, then your last batch will have a smaller number of samples than the other batches. To avoid this, you can force a `tf.data.Dataset` to drop the last batch if it is smaller than the batch size. See [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) for more information.

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_train).batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
```